# Как обратиться к google как из Нью-Йорка?

Tags: ip, google-account

Как обратиться к google как из Нью-Йорка?
Допустим, мне нужна более общая информация, а не то, что гугл дает на запрос из, например, Москвы. Большее, что я могу сделать, - это выбрать в настройках "Россия", т.к. гугл определяет местоположение поставщика моего интернета.

Comment: использовать прокси?

Comment: opera turbo...

Comment: SoloMio, я юзаю мак. Тут в настройках подключения указывается, надо ли использовать прокси-сервер (не знаю как у других). Я хотел бы, чтоб именно к google запросы отправлялись через прокси, а все остальное работало в штатном режиме. Можно ли такое устроить?

Yura Ivanov, спасибо, но это для меня не подходит...

Comment: Да можно, смотри в сторону своего(локального) HTTP прокси, который будет анализировать запросы и выбирать куда их отправлять(в вашем случае напрямую или через прокси в нью-йорке). по софту сильно не подскажу, но вроде керио умеет такое)

Answer (score 2):

Использовать прокси или VPN, располагающийся в NY.

Answer (score 0):

юзай программу tor

а точнее тор браузер

торпроджект

Comment: Разве в [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) можно выбирать конечные точки?

Comment: Можно обновлять свой айпи пока не выпадет нужный, хотя может есть что то менее извращенное :)